# Javascript Form validation not working for select element

Tags: javascript, validation

So I'm trying to change a select box's style if the value is not changed ie. the user has not selected anything. That yesnoCheck is a function which shows an additional input field if the choice "other" is selected. I don't think it affects this form validation though. This same kind of validation works fine with an input field but it won't work with a select box.

I've also treid `selectedIndex == 0` but it doesn't work either.

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return(validate());">
<label for="lastname">Sukunimesi:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />

<select id="car" name="car" onchange="javascript:yesnoCheck()">
    <option id="noCheck" value="none">Valitse automerkkisi</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="1">Lada</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="2">Mosse</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="3">Volga</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="4">Vartburg</option>
    <option id="yesCheck" value="other">Muu</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function yesnoCheck() {
if (document.getElementById("yesCheck").selected) {
    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
}
else document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
}

function validate() {
if (document.myForm.lastname.value.length < 3) {
    document.getElementById("lastname").className = "required";
    return false;
}

if (document.myForm.car.value == "none") {
    document.getElementById("car").className = "required";
    return false;
}
alert ("Everything is fine!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: The default value for no selection is not "none", it's empty, so it's style will not change.

Comment: Well I got it working by removing the "return false;" from the first if-statement

Answer (score 0):

Your code works check your form name and make sure your form exists before the script is run.

```js
function check(){
    if (document.myForm.car.value == "none") {
    document.getElementById("car").style.border = "1px solid #900";
    document.getElementById("car").style.backgroundColor = "#ff9";
    return false;
}
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
    <select id="car" name="car" onchange="javascript:yesnoCheck()">
    <option id="noCheck" value="none">Valitse automerkkisi</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="1">Lada</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="2">Mosse</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="3">Volga</option>
    <option id="noCheck" value="4">Vartburg</option>
    <option id="yesCheck" value="other">Muu</option>
</select>
</form>
<button onclick="check()">Run script</button>
```

Comment: That's weird... I've edited a bit more code into the original post if it makes any difference. If I delete the validation for the input field, it just goes straight to the alert and it skips the other if-statement entirely.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? also try using console.log() inthe steps of the function to check your values

Comment: I'm not getting anything into the console even though I've added console.log() to parts of the function

Comment: Then your function is probably not executing, make sure the function is loaded into the dom before the html. also whats this function onchange="javascript:yesnoCheck()"? does it exists, if not it might be messing with you

Comment: It is executing because the input field changes style when submit button is clicked. I added my whole JS into the original post. And yeah the yesnoCheck() exists and it also works (shows/hides an input box if 'other' is selected)

Comment: really dont know then, even when i copy and paste your code into js fiddle it works perfect.http://jsfiddle.net/kurtrohlandt/Lmcpc32v/1/

Comment: That jsfiddle doesn't work for me. I need the select-box to have that red border as well. I have no clue why it works for the input field but not select :/

Comment: Got it working! Had to remove the "return false;" from the first if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to delete `return false;` from the function.